# C++ Initialize array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How do I initialize a pointer to a literal array?
I want *grid to point to the new allocated int array {1, 2, 3}.

```
int *grid = new int[3];
*grid = {1, 2, 3};
```

thank you.

Comment: Do you want a pointer to a literal array, or do you want to *assign* (i.e. copy) the content of the literal array to a dynamic array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't *initialize* a dynamically allocated array that way. Neither you can *assign* to an array(dynamic or static) in that manner. That syntax is only valid when you initialize a static array, i.e.

```
int a[4] = {2, 5, 6, 4};
```

What I mean is that even the following is illegal:

```
int a[4];
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //Error
```

In your case you can do nothing but copy the velue of each element by hand

```
for (int i = 1; i<=size; ++i)
{
    grid[i-1] = i;
}
```

You might avoid an explicit loop by using stl algorithms but the idea is the same

Some of this may have become legal in C++0x, I am not sure.

Comment: You dont need to init a with 4 elements, it will autoInit.

Comment: @RamonBoza: It will "autoInit" to 0 which isn't always what one wants

Comment: @RamonBoza... ah, you mean I needn't specify 4... yeah, I know, so what? :)

Answer (score 1):

@above grid points to the address location where the first element of the array grid[] is stored. Since in C++ arrays are stored in contiguous memory location, you can walk through your array by just incrementing grid and dereferencing it.

But calling grid an (int*) isnt correct though.

Comment: further note the following: char *s = "Hello World" and char s[] = "Hello World" are radically two different things. In the first case s is of type char* and hence a pointer and it is pointing to the read only memory location which holds "hello word" but in the second case s is an array of char and holds the address of the first memory location which contains this array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is obvious but you can do this in one line.

```
int *grid = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};
```

Since this is C++ we are talking about you can also split it into
two files. Where your `.h` file contains:

```
int *grid;
```

And your `.cpp` file contains:

```
grid = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get the error "expected ';' at end of declaration".  It expects ; after the new int[3], so it doesn't accepts the values initialization

Answer (score -5):

Use the following code, grid is a pointer, grid[] is an element of that pointer.

```
int grid[] = {1 , 2 , 3};
```