# Variable sized pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size

```
Asteroid* rocks[maxAsteroids] = {};
```

So Asteroids is a pointer to a class, at least thats how I understand it. My question is I can't have maxAsteroids be a const, and I know it can't be a simple variable. So what is the proper way to initialize a variable size to a pointer array? This feels like a misunderstanding on my part of syntax, but I'm just not getting it. Appreciated!

Comment: Use dynamic allocation. "On the stack" vanilla arrays cannot be resized and their size must be known at compile time. Or better off use some container class.

Comment: Why not use a vector or some other collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Initialize array pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386329/c-initialize-array-pointer)

Comment: is there an explanation of vector you guys can point (get it?) me to? I saw that around but nothing I read seemed to clear that up.

Comment: "Asteroids" isn't even in your code, let alone being a "pointer to a class". `rocks` is an array. Each member of that array is a pointer that can point to an object of type `Asteroid`, although it is currently a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<Asteroid*> roids;
roids.resize(maxAsteroids);
```

Comment: Thanks that is the answer I needed, though I'll need to look into understanding the vector portion of it, the resize really would have helped to have known about before. Anyway thanks for being so fast.

Comment: the STL is your friend. [This site is also your friend.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)

Comment: @timisaberry - the vector is just a wrapper class around a pointer that points to a dynamic chunk of memory that CAN be resized, and a member that keeps track of how long the vector is. You can just as well use a standalone variables and just use `new [length]` to allocate the array dynamically as big as you want it, `delete []` it and reallocate it when you need. But still using container classes is the recommended practice.

Comment: `vector<Asteroid> rocks;` is much simpler than `vector<Asteroid *>` and should be preferred if it does what you need.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - the object might be big, which will cause a lot of overhead when the vector needs to be resized. Using pointers you can move stuff around without moving the actual objects.

Comment: Where did he say it might be big, and he can't use `reserve`, and that the runtime overhead is measurably slowing down his app?

Comment: Also, `list<Asteroid>` deals with those concerns and is still simpler than using pointers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - reserving doesn't help you much when you need to reorder objects from and to arbitrary positions. And as you become more experienced at programming, you will realize that putting pointers to objects into containers is much more common than putting actual objects. Not only does it offer tremendous advantage as a single object available in multiple different containers at the same time, but sometimes objects are required to have unique identities, making it impossible to move the actual object to another container, you can only use pointers. Dont be arrogant pay attention and learn

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and comments, as always very helpful community.

Comment: I've been a professional programmer for 16 years and my experience is that the simplest solution is the easiest one to both write and maintain. So far OP has said nothing to indicate that adding an extra layer of indirection is necessary for his project.

Comment: @Aesthete: Just curious, why not std::vector<Asteroid*> roids(maxAsteroids)?

Comment: No reason, just avoided having to explain what the constructor args are :)